# Xamarin Forms Properties VS Xamarin Essentials Preferences

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have recently started using the Xamarin Essentials and I personally love the work the team has done on the package.

I was just going through the documents for the same i.e. and I got Across the [Preferences API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?tabs=android) which look slick and work well too.

But what I would personally like to know is what is the actual difference between the Preferences API and the Xamarin Forms Application Properties.

From my research, as of now, `Properties` is an `IDictionary<string,object>` Whereas Preferences is a class that uses the native `SharedPreferences` and `NSUserDefaults` to store data. Now both of them provide the ability to keep persistent properties.

But the documentation doesn't seem to provide me with any ideas as to when I should use which among them.

Also the Xamarin Essentials one highlights a limitation that:

> When storing a string, this API is intended to store small amounts of text. Performance may be subpar if you try to use it to store large amounts of text.

Whereas Application Properties do not have anything as such as you can find here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.application.properties?view=xamarin-forms

Is there anything else that I am missing?

Comment: There is an interesting Channel 9 video of only 5 minutes that tries to explain it. See https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/XamarinShow/Preferences-vs-XamarinForms-Properties-XamarinEssentials-API-of-the-Week

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Application.Properties` Serializes your data and store it in a file on each platform native file system using dependency service. [Here is code the from repo](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Deserializer.cs)

While Preferences API uses platform specific persistent mechanism i.e `User Preference` in android and `User Defaults` in iOS

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have special needs, stick with Xamarin.Essentials because some Xamarin.Forms APIs (I am unsure about this particular one) apparently can be deprecated. For example the Device.OpenUri.

Another thing to consider is the *Secure Storage API*, where you can put encrypted settings such Access tokens in a secure place.

Comment: When was [Device.OpenUri](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.device.openuri?view=xamarin-forms) deprecated? :/

Comment: I got a warning when running an example in preview version (4.3 and up).

Comment: Launcher.CanOpenAsync() & Launcher.OpenAsync();

Comment: Yes, both of them are in xamarin essentials.